# Return Missing balancing numbers

Tags: python, dictionary, listview

A balanced array would be an array in which each element appears the same number of times.

Given an array with n elements:
return a dictionary with the key as the element and the value as the count of elements needed to balance the given array

Examples

```
elements = ["a", "b", "abc", "c", "a"]
```

**Expected output**: `{"b":1, "abc":1, "c":1}`

Because there are 2 `a`, we need 1 more of `b, abc, c`

Hope that helps

Comment: This is obviously homework,  You are expected to make a good effort to solve the problem on your own, then come to us for help.  This is not a code-writing service, and it is unethical to ask us to do your homework for you.  As a hint, look at `collections.Counter`.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to calculate frequencies and then get required frequencies by iterating through it -

```
from collections import Counter
elements = ["a", "b", "abc", "c", "a"]
counts = Counter(elements)
max_freq = max(counts.values())    # 2 in this case
ans = {k: max_freq - v for k, v in counts.items() if v < max_freq}
print(ans)
```

outputs -

```
{'b': 1, 'abc': 1, 'c': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using Counter and lamba. Keeping it simple!

You might want to look into Dictionary Comprehension

```
def return_missing_balanced_numbers(input):
  # Write your code here
  my_dict = {}
  for i in input:
    if i in my_dict:
        my_dict[i] += 1
    else:
        my_dict[i] = 1
  return {a:max(my_dict.values())-b for (a,b) in my_dict.items() if b!= max(my_dict.values())}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't homework but a Meta Data Engineer interview prep question ;)

This is my solution without using Counter

```
lst = ["a", "b", "abc", "c", "a"]    
tuples = [(i, lst.count(i)) for i in lst]
tuples.sort(key=lambda x: -x[1])
max_value = tuples[0]
      
{k: max_value[1] - v for k,v in tuples if v < max_value[1]}
```

Comment: You got it. ;) Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
count = {}
for element in input:
    count[element] = count.get(element,0) + 1

return {key:max(count.values()) - value for (key,value) in count.items() if value != max(count.values())}
```